# Choice between Brute force approach and concurrent threads

Tags: java, graph, traveling-salesman

I have a question concerning graphs. Consider a graph with nodes and edges, each edge having a cost. The problem is to visit all nodes so that the sum of costs of edges traversed is least (Traveling salesman problem, I guess).

Which approach would you recommend? Using brute force approach by recursion or using brute force by spawning threads to concurrently travel different paths and calculate the cost of them.

Or do you have a better way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Since this is a professional web site, and not a chat with your friends on AOL, I suggest you try using proper spelling and grammar.

Comment: Or you could just edit the question for him or tell him more politely since he is a **new** user on this site..

Comment: lol ... People come here to get answers ... Not to act over smart like u ... Answer the question or get out of here ... I post questions the way i want n people will answer for me ... So,stop acting cocky n go get a life kid :P

Answer (score 2):

TSP is NP hard. See wikipedia. It scales horribly.
Multithreading it on a 4 core can make it up to 4 times faster,
which is nothing compared to the 100, 1000 or 1000000 times it goes slower
when you try a slightly larger problem.
Just try it with real sized data, it can take years to finish.

One solution is meta heuristics, there are a couple of libs,
 such as Drools Planner (open source, java).
Take a look at its TTP example.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is simpler, and since it's brute force, multithreading is not guaranteed to get you a solution faster. But before you reinvent the wheel, check out Concorde TSP Solver:

http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/concorde/index.html

It's a free download and includes source.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for multi-threaded approach as it will do things in parallel. As an added optimization I would also keep the lowest cost of a full path in some shared variable and have each thread check that cost - if in between traversal they exceed that cost i would terminate processing immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know why you're doing this nor do I know what your constraints are, I vote for single-thread recursion.  It's easier.

Comment: no big reason ... just preparing for interviews... n companies ask these kinda questions ... so,its better to know :)